# Return all matches for a capturing group in Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am implementing a method that takes in a regex pattern like `r'(\w+/)+end'` and a string `'ab/cd/ef/end'`. Note that I cannot request the caller of the method to update their pattern format. Within the method, I needs to perform an operation that requires extracting all matches of the first capturing group i.e. `ab/`, `cd/`, and `ef/`.

How do I accomplish this in Python? Something like below returns a tuple of last-matches for each of capturing groups. We have just one in this example, so it returns `('ef/',)`.

```py
re.match(r'(\w+/)+end', 'ab/cd/ef/end').groups()
```

By the way, in C#, every capturing group can match multiple strings e.g. `Regex.Match("ab/cd/ef/end", @"(\w+/)+end").Groups[1].Captures` will return all the three matches for first capturing group `(\w+/)+`.

Comment: Cannot accept the answers. I already mentioned that it's not possible to change the regex. Extracting pattern-text within capturing groups parentheses could be error prone. I will go ahead with using regex project (https://pypi.org/project/regex/). It nicely solves my problem: `regex.match(r'(\w+/)+end', 'ab/cd/ef/end').captures(1)` returns `['ab/', 'cd/', 'ef/']`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture all path names which are followed by a separator, then use the pattern `\w+/` with `re.findall`:

```
inp = "ab/cd/ef/end"
matches = re.findall(r'\w+/', inp)
print(matches)

['ab/', 'cd/', 'ef/']
```

If instead you want all path components, whether or not they be preceded by a path separator, then we can try:

```
inp = "ab/cd/ef/end"
matches = re.findall(r'[^/]+', inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = r"(\w+/)(?<!end)"
s = "ab/cd/ef/end"

m = re.finditer(r, s, re.MULTILINE)

for g in m:
    print(g.group())
```

**Example**:

https://regex101.com/r/VJ6knI/1